# SSH: remove key authentication to setup a new one

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a VM with an OpenSSH server running on it. I messed up my SSH server public key authentication setting (installed everything in my SSH session on the VM and not from an external terminal on my computer). I can SSH from my Debian session on the VM with the public key but this makes no sense.

I need to remove entirely my SSH key athentication so I can setup a new one correctly and be able to SSH from my OSX terminal to the server running on the VM.

What can I do to start all over clean?

Sorry for being such a noob.

Answer (score 0):

in the client ssh fingerprint of known_hosts are saved under `~/.ssh/known_hosts` in the server the authorized_key are installed under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` so depending if you want to clean up the installed key on the server, cancel the entry or remove the whole file authorized_keys.

If you can still connect to your ssh server with username and password you can just install the new client key with:

```
ssh-copy-id user@server
```

then provide the password and the ssh key are installed.

Instead, if the ssh server does not work anymore with password authentication you have two way to proceed:

1. install the ssh key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (simpli copy and paste a in a newline of the file)
2. Permit again in to ssh the password login by modify this in the /etc/ssh/sshd_conf

   PasswordAuthentication yes

after the password authentication is restored you can install the ssh key with ssh-copy-id from the bash you desired.

Comment: Can I remove what's in the client .ssh folder?

Comment: in the .ssh of the client normally is also stored your id_rsa which you install in to the remote host, that may you want to keep; may I should clarify better my answer to you.